# How can I ignore all email messages in a conversation without deleting them in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: notifications, outlook-on-the-web

How can I ignore all email messages in a conversation without deleting them in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

The [Ignore Conversation feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ignore-all-email-messages-in-a-conversation-5ec0c3c2-3440-484e-9aca-0588234d44e9) removes all messages related to the conversation that you select, and moves future messages in the conversation directly to your Deleted Items folder.

> #### Ignore conversation?
>
> This conversation and all future responses will be moved to the Deleted Items folder

I'm pretty much looking for the equivalent of [Gmail's mute feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576) which automatically skips the inbox for all future messages of a muted conversation.

Comment: Have you looked at OOW's [Focused Inbox](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/organize-email-with-outlook-on-the-web-c5a22636-6a10-4f96-a9e5-1f1071cde749) feature?  You can select a message to  **Always move to `Other`** I think it only works for senders not conversations but depending on the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a similar feature in Outlook. One workaround is to set up a rule that marks those messages as read and archive them.

[image]